# Using Includes in a Function to show block if included in a Picklist

Tags: picklist

I'm intending the following:
• If the system_picks field includes the text "Medication Dispenser", make the div with the id "ifYesMed" visible.
• Otherwise, hide the div "ifYesMed"

What am I missing in the code below?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.styleforAccountLightningPage}"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
  
<div id="ifYesMed">
  <div id="medDeviceNumber">
    <span> Medication Dispenser Device Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:OutputField value="{!Account.MED_Device_Number__c}"/> </span>
  </div>
</div>  
    
<script>
     
function showMedNumber (){    
       if (INCLUDES(Systems_Pick__c, "Medication Dispenser")){
            document.getElementById("ifYesMed").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ifYesMed").style.display = "none";
        }
}

</script>
</apex:page>
```

Per recommendations, I have updated my function to

```
function showMedNumber (){    
       if (CONTAINS(Systems_Pick__c, "Medication Dispenser")){
            <apex:outputPanel>
            document.getElementById("ifYesMed").style.display = "block";
            </apex:outputPanel>
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ifYesMed").style.display = "none";
        }
}
```

I'm still not getting the intended results.  Can anyone assist by letting me know how I should change my code exactly? Thank you!

Comment: You want `apex:outputPanel` with `IF(CONTAINS(...))` condition. See the referenced answer for an example of `apex:outputPanel`. If you do a search on here, you'll find many other examples.

Comment: The reason you're better off following identigral's approach is that you are mixing Visualforce functions with JavaScript. They are not the same language and are tricky to get working together. Also, if security is a concern, you never ever want to use CSS to hide something from a page because the information is still passed over the network and included in the DOM.

Comment: I'm still not getting the intended results. Can anyone assist by letting me know how I should change my code exactly? Thank you! I'm pretty new at this, and need a bit more hand-holding at the moment. Confused by searching other posts.

Comment: @AlexFrisch Go through [Visualforce Basics trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals), it will give you more foundational knowledge.

Comment: in addition to other remarks, the VF functions need to be wrapped in `{!` and `}`